# Does a closure over a React event handler save my component from unecessary rerenders?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures

I read that anonymous function callbacks in JSX event handlers are a performance anti-pattern because they create unnecessary rerenders. Someone suggested that I should instead use a named function. No problem for a typical case where I only care about the event being passed in. The problem in my use case is that I need to pass additional parameters in to this callback.

I can't change `onClick={handleClick}` to `onClick={handleClick(additionalParam)}` because now I've got a function invocation, not a function reference.

So I started thinking, "what if that invocation returns a function with the signature I want?"

The solution I came up with involved using a closure over the callback with the desired additional parameters. I have an example below. Does this save me from rerenders? If not, what's wrong or how can I fix this?

#### Original version with anonymous function

```js
const StudentButtonBlock = () => {
    const handleClick = (e, analyticsData) => {
        fireAnalytics('click: student button', {
            ...analyticsData
        });
    };

    return (
        <div className="student-button-block">
            {students.map(student => (
                <button
                    key={student.name}
                    handleClick={e => handleClick(e, { source: student.name })}>
                    Click Me
                </button>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};
```

#### Modified version with closure

```js
const StudentButtonBlockModified = () => {
    const handleClick = analyticsData => {
        fireAnalytics('click: student button', {
            ...analyticsData
        });
    };

    const handleClickWithStudent = student => {
        return () => {
            handleClick({ source: student.name });
        };
    };

    return (
        <div className="student-button-block">
            {students.map(student => (
                <button
                    key={student.name}
                    handleClick={handleClickWithStudent(student)}>
                    Click Me
                </button>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: No this doesn't preserve a constant reference. The closure needs to be memoized, and react already provides that with `React.useCallback()`

Comment: Does `handleClick = { handleClick({ source: student.name }) }` not work?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Thanks! I'd heard of React Hooks before but now that I have stumbled across a real use case `useCallback` seems like it's exactly what I need.